# Method sharing between activities Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How can i make one method available for multiple activities in android? It's done by inheritance, but since every activity i have extends ActionBarActivity, and multiple inheritance is not possible, i have ran out of options.

This is all to avoid having much duplicate code.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Favor composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have one Activity that extends ActionBarActivity that has the method the others need to inherit. Then have the other Activities extend that one Activity.